# Blender Geo nodes offset curve

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves

So I am in the process of writing a geo node modifier where I can create curves that are offset from the original curve by a certain amount.

I would like to be able to offset the curves by an amount that changes along the curve
(see image bellow) but I am not certain how to do that.

here are the main nodes
[image]

here are the nodes that calculates the offset:
[image]

here is the current result:
[image]

and here is the desired outcome, where green is the main curve and red are the created curves:
[image]

Comment: What values are in the divide nodes?

Comment: the value is 0.5 to get another curve between the outermost and the center one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the curve factor to get a range between 0 and 1 along the curve.

That way, you can control the offset strength along the curve. Use a map range node if you want to have more control over the offset settings

Also, you should use a duplicate elements node instead of making a group for each curves, its better for performances and compatibility

[image]

[image]